# How to add a set of object into a single array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I'm inserting a list of email recipient with same subject and message but different recipients.

I've already tried some method shown below, it get's the number of recipients to be sent, but it for the recipient it only get's the last recipient pushed into the array, that's why it was sent to the same recipient 3 times.

````
        var emailsObj = [];
        var addEmailObj = [], obj;
        for (i=0 ; i<rowData.length; i++) {
            addEmailObj["claimNo"] = $('#motorClaimNoInfo').val().trim().toUpperCase();
            addEmailObj["fileNo"] = $('#motorClaimNoInfo').attr('fileNo');
            addEmailObj["claimDate"] = $('#motorClaimNoInfo').attr('claimDate');
            addEmailObj["senderCd"] = $('#motorClaimFileComposeEmailFrom').attr('username');
            addEmailObj["sender"] = $('#motorClaimFileComposeEmailFrom').val();
            addEmailObj["senderEmail"] = $('#motorClaimFileComposeEmailFrom').attr('userEmail');
            addEmailObj["recipientCd"] = rowData[i].username;
            addEmailObj["recipient"] = rowData[i].userFullName;
            addEmailObj["recipientEmail"] = rowData[i].userEmail;
            addEmailObj["subject"] = $('#motorClaimFileComposeEmailSubj').val().trim().toUpperCase();
            addEmailObj["message"] = $('#motorClaimFileComposeEmailMsg').val().trim().toUpperCase();
            emailObj.push(addEmailObj[i]);
            emailsObj.push(rowData[i].username);
        }

Here's the console for this code
```[INFO ] 2019-05-06 14:25:37.766 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] MotorClaimInquiryController - emailObj {claimNo=100161002000351, fileNo=1, claimDate=11-21-2016, senderCd=MGSIMBIL, sender=MICHELLE G. SIMBILLO, senderEmail=MGSIMBILLO@MAPFREINSULAR.COM, recipientCd=ABSERNIO, recipient=SERNIO, ANNABEL BENAS, recipientEmail=ABSERNIO@MAPFREINSULAR.COM, subject=100161002000351-01, message=}
[INFO ] 2019-05-06 14:25:39.059 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] MotorClaimInquiryController - emailObj {claimNo=100161002000351, fileNo=1, claimDate=11-21-2016, senderCd=MGSIMBIL, sender=MICHELLE G. SIMBILLO, senderEmail=MGSIMBILLO@MAPFREINSULAR.COM, recipientCd=ABSERNIO, recipient=SERNIO, ANNABEL BENAS, recipientEmail=ABSERNIO@MAPFREINSULAR.COM, subject=100161002000351-01, message=}
[INFO ] 2019-05-06 14:25:40.578 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] MotorClaimInquiryController - emailObj {claimNo=100161002000351, fileNo=1, claimDate=11-21-2016, senderCd=MGSIMBIL, sender=MICHELLE G. SIMBILLO, senderEmail=MGSIMBILLO@MAPFREINSULAR.COM, recipientCd=ABSERNIO, recipient=SERNIO, ANNABEL BENAS, recipientEmail=ABSERNIO@MAPFREINSULAR.COM, subject=100161002000351-01, message=}

The result should have different recipients. Thanks
````

Comment: Shouldn't `addEmailObj` be an object `{}`?

Comment: you need to empty the `addEmailObj ` fir each loop. Try having `addEmailObj = {}` inside your for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only assigning to `addEmailObj` once:

```
var addEmailObj = []
```

This means that every time you mutate or push `addEmailObj`, you're mutating or pushing the *same object*. Create it inside the array instead:

```
for (let i=0 ; i<rowData.length; i++) {
  const addEmailObj = {};
```

Note that since you're not using it as an array, you shouldn't define it as an array - just define it as a plain object, with `{}`, not `[]`. (Also, best not to implicitly create global variables - declare your `i` properly) If at all possible, also declare your variables with ES6 syntax (`let` and `const`) rather than ES5 syntax to avoid the confusion that can arise from `var`'s hoisting. (`var` has function scope, not block scope)

Comment: But since it's not in a function, `var` would produce the same output - it should be `let`.

Comment: The assignment is inside the loop - it'll work fine. https://jsfiddle.net/subp416h/ (though, yeah, better to avoid `var` if possible)

Comment: So would that mean that at the end of each iteration, it would be destroyed/garbage collected?

Comment: Because the created object (using either `var` or `const`) gets pushed to the array, it won't be garbage collected as long as the array remains visible. Using `var` would make the *last* created object visible to the whole function though, which could be a potential source of bugs in the future. If `var`, reassigning `addEmailObj` inside the loop won't destroy what the variable used to refer to, it'll just reference a new object in memory (until it gets reassigned again)

Comment: Ok, I get it now - thanks! I'm still learning the ropes of garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
               // let emailsObj = [];
            let addEmailObj = [];
            for (i=0 ; i<rowData.length; i++) {

    let new_user = {
        'claimNo':$('#motorClaimNoInfo').val().trim().toUpperCase(),
        'fileNo':$('#motorClaimNoInfo').attr('fileNo'),
        'claimDate':$('#motorClaimNoInfo').attr('claimDate'),
        'senderCd':$('#motorClaimFileComposeEmailFrom').attr('username'),
        'sender':$('#motorClaimFileComposeEmailFrom').val(),
        'senderEmail':$('#motorClaimFileComposeEmailFrom').attr('userEmail'),
        'recipientCd':rowData[i].username,
        'recipient':rowData[i].userFullName,
        'recipientEmail':rowData[i].userEmail,
        'subject':$('#motorClaimFileComposeEmailSubj').val().trim().toUpperCase(),
        'message':$('#motorClaimFileComposeEmailMsg').val().trim().toUpperCase()

    };
                addEmailObj.push(new_user);
                // emailsObj.push(rowData[i].username);
            }**

>
```